# java SpringBoot jar crashes on CentOS

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a very simple SpringBoot application which implements a simple Rest API.

This is the way I start it:

```
package API;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
    }
}
```

The controller is placed in the same package as this one (the `API` package).

This is my maven file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>HadoopDriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>HadoopDriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.30</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.338</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I develop this app in IntelliJ Idea, on macOS and I generate a JAR that I place on a Cent OS (EC2) machine and I want to run it from there.

I generate the manifest file like that: *File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> + -> JAR -> From Modules with dependencies -> select the Main class -> change the directory of the META-INF to /resources instead of /java -> Apply -> OK*.

The I go on *Build -> Build Artifacts -> Build* and then I get my JAR that is placed in the `/out/artifacts/project_jar` folder.

I upload this jar to the Cent OS machine and when I try to run it I get the following output:

```
user@host>
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::
user@host>
```

I get no error message, no nothing. I don't know where to look for errors, I don't have any clue on how to solve this issue.

Please tell me at least where to look, how can I diagnose this problem because I'm trying for a lot of time with no result.

Comment: For starters it doesn't seem like you have any logging enabled - which is probably why you're not able to see any logs.  Could you enable that?  (You should just strip out Log4J since Log4J 1.x is end of life and should *not* be used in anything modern.  Spring Boot's logback logging style is *just fine* for your needs. :))

Comment: I don't know how to enable logging. I created a log4j.properties file but I don't know how to make it work

Comment: Rip it out.  You don't need Log4J.  Rip out any custom logging you've had in there.  Spring Boot ships with Logback and will automatically log to stdout, so you *shouldn't* need anything just to get some info.

Comment: In your application.properties file, add `logging.level.org.springframework=debug`, and that'd give you debug level logging in Spring Boot.

Comment: I haven't used until now an application.properties file. I created a new one now and I added it in the /resources folder, I put that line, I rebuilt the jar and uploaded it to the machine but the error is still the same. Should I place this application.properties file in another location?

Comment: It should live in src/main/resources, and should be part of the built JAR you're trying to execute.

Comment: okay so if I add it in that directory, shouldn't it be automatically included in the JAR? is there a specific thing I have to do in order to include that file into the JAR?

Comment: ...you have to rebuild the app...

Comment: it worked! Now I got an exception that I have to solve! You are amazing, man!

Comment: I'll codify this as an answer then.

Comment: Yes, please do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use Log4J in your application, for a couple of reasons:

- It's [at end of life](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces)
- Spring Boot already ships with Logback and other ways to configure logging

In your case, you may not be getting enough detail in your logs.  Crank up the verbosity by adding this to your `application.properties` file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

This will allow you to see debug logs in stdout from everything living underneath `org.springframework`.